# JavaScript submit form fields to PHP back-end throws Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, php, rest, drupal-8, decoupling

I have two sites running separately, where the front end is one end, which connects to multiple back-end systems.

The end goal is to be able to submit a form with text and video fields to a PHP(Drupal) back-end.

For this, my HTML and JS look like the following:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="sample_image" id="sample_image">
    <div id="uploaded_image"></div>
</form>
<script>

    const first_name = document.querySelector("#first_name");
    const surname = document.querySelector("#surname");
    const message = document.querySelector("#message");
    const sample_image = document.getElementsByName("sample_image")[0];

    sample_image.addEventListener('change', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        upload_image(sample_image.files[0])
    })

    const upload_image = (file) => {            
        const form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("sample_image", file);

        let data = {
            "webform_id": "springboks",
            "first_name": first_name.value,
            "surname": surname.value,
            "message": message.value,
            "video": form_data
        };

        fetch("http://localhost:49640/api/v1/form/14436545/CBUFormSubmission", {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            params: { '_format': 'json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(responseData){
            console.log("responseData")
            console.log(responseData)
        })
    }
</script>
```

For now, am running the script during file upload, and am getting the following in the console:

```
http://localhost:49640/api/v1/form/14436545/CBUFormSubmission net::ERR_ABORTED 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

However, I get a successful response when doing the submission using Insomnia, obviously without the file and the setup is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is also the payload(without the file for now) when I look at developer tools:
[image]

In code, with or without the file I get the 415 response. And this is with or without the video.

How do I submit the form data to the backend system?

Comment: "The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.". Which `Accept` headers  you got in response?

Comment: But how come the request works if I try on postman/insomnia? From the server side I do not do much because the post resource headers are preconfigured by Drupal.

Comment: Try to compare your request's body and `Content-Type` headers on postman/frontend requests, there is a some difference between them, I guess. Attach screenshot from Postman to this questions, please

Comment: the `JSON.stringify` does not work with `FormData` (nor `File` btw), so the file is not even present in the request, i have no idea how to upload file with `'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json'`, perhaps read the backend documentation, or use regular `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I edited my question to clarify on the insomnia setup as well as the content type.

Comment: well again, the `JSON.stringify` is the root cause of your issues, JSON is format which can represent basic data formats, arrays and raw objects, but you are not able to store file there, not without some text transformation which has to be done on both sides in order to work, so as you can see the JSON itself is inappropriate for this use case. inspect your request in developer tools you will see that the post data are almost empty, only `"webform_id": "springboks",` gets there and nothing else, why ? because `first_name` etc. are elements which are not JSON stringifiable, `form_data` as well

Comment: The form data thing is a problem but not the reason for the unsupported media type error which is caused by no-CORS mode (which prevents from from setting the content-type to application/json in the first place).

Comment: @Kazz I noticed not adding the .value on each field but edited my answer to reflect this as well as my result over dev tools.
Once again, am having issues with or without the file being uploaded.

Comment: @Quentin how will I be able to bypass the cors error without the no-cors flag?

Comment: By implementing CORS on the server.